# API: How to add the prefix field to shipping and billing address?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

On Magento 1.9, I need to add the field `prefix` to the `shipping_address` and `billing_address` nodes in the response of `salesOrderInfo` (soap-api-v2). I tried by adding the following:

> **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml:**

`<xsd:element name="prefix" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />` (line 275)

> **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml:**

`<element name="prefix" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />` (line 274)

The prefix field contains a value (I can verify it with debug breakpoints in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api::info()`) However, the SOAP response still does not contain the field. I even tried to set a `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);` in the index.php to disable the wsdl cache, flushed the regular cache, restarted the Apache server, but with no success.

Does anybody have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. I just restarted the computer with the changes listed above and the response contained the field `prefix`. I have no idea which cache was involved (I had flushed them all), apparently one was still returning the old field structure.